# Sql query which one is faster

Tags: sql

The first query is this

```
Select Name
     , Surname
     , ClassID 
  from classes
     , users 
 where classes.UserId = users.UserID 
    OR classes.UserID = 0
```

The second query is this

```
Select Name
     , Surname
     , ClassID 
  from classes 
  left 
  join users 
    on classes.UserId = users.UserID
```

The classes table have UserID 0 variable and i add the query OR classes.UserID=0

I don't have big data i can't try it. Someone can help me ? which is faster and why ?

Comment: Run these in Workbench or Sysyog, it will tell you query execution times.

Comment: the query are not the same  .. the first  had more condition  than the second .. (the or clause is aggiuntive) and then should be faster the second

Comment: mysql or sql server or mariadb?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy its a query ? what the differancies about them ?

Comment: The two queries are doing two different things, so comparing relative performance is meaningless.

Comment: but the two query give me same result

Comment: No. The two queries are entirely different. If they give the same result, that's merely coincidence.

Comment: Incidentally, building big tables is really easy - it takes a few seconds to generate a large data set.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Mysql database sir/lady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second query is faster.

The first query combines all options from classes and users and then filters by the conditions specified in the where clause.

The second query filters while going through all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Cross join { classes,users } gives you a cross product of records which is m X n and applying filter on that whereas other approach directly uses left join and gets the required data and hence second query will be faster and better

Comment: you beat me to it

Comment: This assertion is incorrect - as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS will confirm. The first query is NOT a CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are strikingly different.

The first is going to repeat user 0 for every class -- after doing an inner join.  The second is going to keep all the classes, with a `NULL` value when the user doesn't match.

First, you should use the query that correctly implements the logic you want.  Correctness is more important than performance.

Second, you should never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Third, the second is probably what you want. It has the more reasonable result set.